# R: regex to delete zero terms in equations

Tags: regex, r

I have the following character matrix, representing a system of linear equations:

```
  > dput(eq)
  structure(c("0*x1 + 1*x2 - 1*x3   =   8", "-3*x1 + 0*x2 + 2*x3   =   -11", 
  "-2*x1 + 1*x2 + 0*x3   =   -3"), .Dim = c(3L, 1L))
```

That is,

```
> eq
     [,1]                           
[1,] "0*x1 + 1*x2 - 1*x3   =   8"   
[2,] "-3*x1 + 0*x2 + 2*x3   =   -11"
[3,] "-2*x1 + 1*x2 + 0*x3   =   -3"
```

In a function, I'd like to delete all terms of the form `"0*x\d"`.  The following gets me part way there, but misses the `"0*x3"` term in the last equation.  Can someone help?

```
> gsub("0\\*x\\d [+-]", "", eq)
     [,1]                          
[1,] " 1*x2 - 1*x3   =   8"        
[2,] "-3*x1 +  2*x3   =   -11"     
[3,] "-2*x1 + 1*x2 + 0*x3   =   -3"
```

Comment: You need to put `[+-]` optional.Like `[+-]|\\s` or remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your regex like below,

```
gsub("0\\*x\\d\\s+[+-]|[+-]\\s+0\\*x\\d", "", eq)

#     [,1]                     
#[1,] " 1*x2 - 1*x3   =   8"   
#[2,] "-3*x1  + 2*x3   =   -11"
#[3,] "-2*x1 + 1*x2    =   -3"
```